# Trouble getting POST to work with swift

Tags: php, mysql, swift, post

I am trying to send data from my app to a MySql database. I successfully connect to the database, through my php script, but only blank entries are recorded. ie name = "".
I think I am encoding the data incorrectly but I am not sure.

```
    let name = "test"
    let url = NSURL(string: posturl)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var postString: NSString = "name=\(name)"
```

This is where I believe I am making some mistake, but honestly I'm not sure. I am not very familiar with swift/iOS development at all!

```
    var data: NSData = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    request.HTTPBody = data
```

Also, I was wondering if this is necessary. I saw it used in examples but am uncertain if it's of use.

```
    var conString: NSString = NSString(format:"%u", data.length)
    request.setValue(conString as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
```

Finally, I make the connection

```
    var conn =  NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
    conn!.start()
```

Comment: UTF8 is usually used, not ASCII. Have you tried that?

Comment: try to avoid use of NSURLConnection as it has been deprecated in iOS 9. instead of use NSURLSession

Comment: Thanks it appears as though I simply forgot what input my server POST method required! OOPS. Now it is working with both encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSASCIIStringEncoding` should be `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and try to make it Asynchronous for better performance

```
 let posturl: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
 var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: posturl)!
 var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
 request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 var postString = "name=\(name)" // Key and Value
 let data = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
 request1.timeoutInterval = 60
 request1.HTTPBody=data
 request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false
 let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
       var err: NSError
       var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println("AsSynchronous\(jsonResult)")
 })
```